# PHP Unixtimestamp get the day of the year

Tags: php, mysql

Is there anyway to get the day of the year from Unixtimestamp? Like I only want the outprint e.g "251".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo date('z', $timestamp) + 1;
```

The `z` format character for [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) will give you the day of the year but it starts counting at zero so you must add 1 to it to get the actual day of the year.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('z',date('U'))+1;
```

- U    Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)
- z    The    day of the year (starting from 0)

Comment: Why use `date('U')` when you can use `time()`?